# PyCharm not adding sources root to `sys.path`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

In a run configuration in PyCharm I've check both:

- `Add content roots to PYTHONPATH`
- `Add source roots to PYTHONPATH`

But I can't import files relative to my sources root. This is a new installation of PyCharm (system rebuild) and an existing project & run configurations which worked before now fail.

In the Python Console I print the value of `sys.path` and see my content root, but not the source root listed. I double check the Project Structure and see the directory `src` is listed as a Source Folder appropriately.

When I run python at the console from the source root directory all imports work as expected.

Any idea what configuration I might be missing in PyCharm to cause this? Or perhaps my expectation is incorrect?

Comment: I think I had this go away by restarting PyCharm. It helps to diagnose by looking at `sourceFolder`s in `.idea/MyProject.xml` and `os.environ["PYTHONPATH"].split(':')`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution here:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000164624-SOLVED-pycharm-seem-to-fail-to-add-to-PYTHONPATH

Just delete the `.idea` project directory and re-create the project to fix the problem.